# Panda csv itertools combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, python-itertools

My dataset looks like this,

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       10      x1
B       100     x2
C       1000    x3
```

This is what I am getting my output to look like,

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9
A       10      x1      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty
B       100     x2      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty
C       1000    x3      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty
A       10      x1      B       100     x2      Empty   Empty   Empty
B       100     x2      C       1000    x3      Empty   Empty   Empty
A       10      x1      B       100     x2      C       1000    x3
```

Thanks to help from this website, this can be done with -

```
arr = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
[[j for i in el for j in i] for el in itertools.combinations(df.values.tolist(), i)]
for i in range(1, len(df)+1)
)
)

pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

But if the dataset was the following,

```
        Col1 Col2   Col3   Structure
        A    10     x1     1
        B    100    x2     1
        C    1000   x3     2
```

And the output needed to be this -

```
  Col1    Col2    Col3      Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Answer
    A       10      x1      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   No
    B       100     x2      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   No
    C       1000    x3      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Yes
    A       10      x1      B       100     x2      Empty   Empty   Empty   Yes
    B       100     x2      C       1000    x3      Empty   Empty   Empty   No
    A       10      x1      B       100     x2      C       1000    x3      No
```

Which is basically saying A and B are 'YES' because they are in the same structure and C by itself is 'YES because it is in the structure by itself.
All the other rows such as A, B, ABC are 'NO' because they are not in the same structure. How do I get the above desired table?

The code,

```
arr = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
[[j for i in el for j in i] for el in itertools.combinations(df.values.tolist(), i)]
for i in range(1, len(df)+1)
)
)

pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

gives me this output,

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9
    A       10      x1      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty
    B       100     x2      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty
    C       1000    x3      Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty
    A       10      x1      B       100     x2      Empty   Empty   Empty
    B       100     x2      C       1000    x3      Empty   Empty   Empty
    A       10      x1      B       100     x2      C       1000    x3
```

How do I add the 'Answer' column to this output to get the ultimate table?

Comment: This is just an observation because it will take me a bit more thought to try answer your question, but I'm really not sure I'd want to be tasked with maintaining the approach you're currently using. There's a lot going on there.

Comment: I believe one approach could be to concatenate col1, col4 and col7 and do left join to original df. Wherever there would be a structure match you will get the value. replace it will 'yes' and rest with 'no'

Comment: Another approach could concatenate the columns first and use lambda but it will require to iterate over the previous df again and again and hence the earlier approach should be better.

Comment: If you're going to use the code I posted as an answer on your other question, maybe consider accepting it as an answer :P

Comment: @user3483203, I thought I did! Just checked it and accepted it! 
You mind helping me out with this one now? :P

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why `A` and `B` alone are not `Yes`, When they're alone there is no mixture of groups.  Is it only a `Yes` if *all* members of the group are present?

Comment: Yes, it would be a 'Yes' only if all the members are present. I am trying to structure the data in a particular way to feed it into a machine learning model. So, the goal is to make sure it learns that only particular cases when together form the structures. In this case, A alone and B alone would not qualify but A and B qualify to form a structure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the structure of the DataFrame, we know that when we apply `itertools.combinations`, the `Structure` column will show up first in the 3rd column, and every fourth column following:

```
  0     1   2   3     4       5     6    7     8       9     10   11
0  A    10  x1   1  None     NaN  None  NaN  None     NaN  None  NaN
1  B   100  x2   1  None     NaN  None  NaN  None     NaN  None  NaN
2  C  1000  x3   2  None     NaN  None  NaN  None     NaN  None  NaN
3  A    10  x1   1     B   100.0    x2  1.0  None     NaN  None  NaN
4  A    10  x1   1     C  1000.0    x3  2.0  None     NaN  None  NaN
5  B   100  x2   1     C  1000.0    x3  2.0  None     NaN  None  NaN
6  A    10  x1   1     B   100.0    x2  1.0     C  1000.0    x3  2.0
```

We can use this to index only the `Structure` columns, check if they contain all members of a group, then drop them:

```
checker = df.groupby('Structure').size().to_dict()

def helper(row):                                               
    u = row[~row.isnull()].values                              
    return (len(np.unique(u)) == 1) & (checker[u[0]] == len(u))

s = out[out.columns[3::4]].apply(helper, 1).replace({False: 'No', True: 'Yes'})

0     No
1     No
2    Yes
3    Yes
4     No
5     No
6     No
dtype: object
```

To drop the other columns and assign to the DataFrame:

```
out.drop(out.columns[3::4], 1).assign(final=s)

   0     1   2     4       5     6     8       9    10 final
0  A    10  x1  None     NaN  None  None     NaN  None    No
1  B   100  x2  None     NaN  None  None     NaN  None    No
2  C  1000  x3  None     NaN  None  None     NaN  None   Yes
3  A    10  x1     B   100.0    x2  None     NaN  None   Yes
4  A    10  x1     C  1000.0    x3  None     NaN  None    No
5  B   100  x2     C  1000.0    x3  None     NaN  None    No
6  A    10  x1     B   100.0    x2     C  1000.0    x3    No
```